# How to remove the .html part of the URL on Azure?

Tags: azure

Say, I want to turn this: `www.example.com/homepage.html` to this `www.example.com/homepage`

What should I change in my Azure portal or config in order to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think this is something you configure in the portal. Rather, you configure it in your app. Is it ASP.NET, Node, ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could place this block of code in your `web.config` file.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Hide .html ext">
             <match ignoreCase="true" url="^(.*)"/>
             <conditions>
                 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html" matchType="IsFile"/>
             </conditions>
             <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.html"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="Redirecting .html ext" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*).html"/>
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                 <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*).html"/>
             </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}"/>
         </rule>
   </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This will remove the `.html` extension from **every** html file. So, for example, if you open a file called index.html it would be shown as index and if you request the file index it will be shown the index.html file (the extension will not be shown).

This works both on Azure and on IIS, so if in a future you would move to IIS, you could do without changing anything.

I hope i helped you.