# IIS web.config Issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I recently switched from LAMP on a dedicated server hosted on RackSpace to a Azure Webapp. I have a PHP application that was wrote in a way that doesn't always include the .php at the end of the redirects, and wants to hide the .php in the URL whenever possible.

Using a .htaccess to web.config convertor  I came up this, but I get an internal server error on ANY page i go to... .php or not. If I remove the web.config I can access the pages by forcing the .php in the url.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
<rewrite>
    <rule name="hide php extension" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)/$" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" />
    </rule>
</rules>
</rewrite> 
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Am I missing something? I would think that it would be easy, but clearly it is beyond my capabilities. I've played around with various rules posted here, but do not know enough about IIS yet to write my own rules.

Comment: try: <match url="(.*)" />  remove logicalGrouping="MatchAll" ..  and change   ignoreCase="true" . Restart IIS

Comment: No dice. I've tried several other examples since then. I wonder if there something specific with Azure that is causing the issue?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Please do some troubleshooting.

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55757746/how-to-remove-php-extension-on-azure-php-web-app AND https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579455/how-to-remove-the-html-part-of-the-url-on-azure

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add below rule in your web.config file:

```
 <rule name="Redirect .php extension" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
  <match url="^(.*).php$" ignoreCase="true" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
  <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*).php$" ignoreCase="false" />
</conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>

<rule name="hide .php extension" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
<conditions>
  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php" matchType="IsFile" />
</conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.php" />
</rule>
```

[image]

Regards,
Jalpa